# jQuery conflict when using wp_editor() in front end

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I'm trying to use the tinyMCE editor in the front end with the wp_editor() function (new as of WP 3.3 I believe).  However, whenever I include it in a post in the front end (through a shortcode) jQuery stops working.

The [codex says](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor): "Once instantiated, the WYSIWYG editor cannot be moved around in the DOM. What this means in practical terms, is that you cannot put it in meta-boxes that can be dragged and placed elsewhere on the page."

I'm wondering if the problem that I'm experiencing is related and if there is a fix.

Comment: For anybody else that is having this same problem, I switched my jQuery wrapper from `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...});` which executes when the page finishes loading to `(function($){...})(jQuery);` which executes immediately. It's not ideal though, so if someone else has any thoughts, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround for this problem is to shut down the tinymce instance and reinitialize it after the tinymce related html element has been moved.

Tinymce cannot be moved around in the DOM without reinitialisation!